# Let X be the set of all functions from the empty set to set A, is X={{}}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This was the question in my test, I answered false because I thought it was the empty set, since there is no function that maps the empty set to another set.
However I also know that the cardinality of the set of functions from one set to another is n^m, with n being the cardinality of the codomain and m of the domain. Using this the cardinality should be 1, which is exactly |{{}}|, while |{}| is 0.
So I'm not sure about which one is right and if the answer should be false or true, can someone help me out?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve your mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f\colon X\to Y$ is a subset of $X\times Y$, by definition. In the case that $X=\varnothing$ we also have $X\times Y=\varnothing$, and the only subset of $\varnothing$ (which is $\varnothing$) vacuously satisfies the properties defining a function.

So if $X=\varnothing$ there is exactly one function $X\to Y$, namely the empty function, hence the correct answer would have been "true".

Answer (score 0):

There is only one function from $\{\}$ into $A$, which is $\{\}$.Therefore, yes, the set of all functions from $\{\}$ into $A$ is $\bigl\{\{\}\bigr\}$. And, indeed,$$\left\lvert\bigl\{\{\}\bigr\}\right\rvert=1=\lvert A\rvert^0=\lvert A\rvert^{\lvert \{\}\rvert}.$$